# Difference in Image constructors

Tags: java, javafx, inputstream

In JavaFX 8, what is the difference between loading an Image with the InputStream constructor and loading an Image with the url constructor.

If I use

```
private Image getImage(String s){
    return new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fruit/" +s+".png"));
}
```

Does it do the same thing as

```
private Image getImage(String s){
    return new Image("/fruit/" +s+".png");
}
```

First I thought the latter wouldn't work when I compiled it as a jar but it does.
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) is a link to the API of Image.

Comment: There is minimal difference: just use whichever is most convenient. If you omit the leading `/`, `getResourceAsStream(...)` will search relative to the current class, whereas the `String` version will search relative to the classpath. If you are loading from a database BLOB field, or a network socket, for example, the `InputStream` option will be your only option.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the biggest difference is where the system will search for the file. If you export your project into an executable JAR file, you will notice that `Image(InputStream)` will allow you to search within your JAR file, while `Image(String)` will only allow you to search outside your JAR file.